# Getting array length by destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript

After reading the MDN doc with examples of [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and there is an example like:

```js
const [a, b, ...{ pop, push }] = [1, 2];
console.log(a, b); // 1 2
console.log(pop, push); // [Function pop] [Function push]
```

and it says: `This allows you to simultaneously unpack the properties and indices of arrays.`

I took a second thought, isn't it will be fascinating if I could get the length of the array by doing this assignment at the same time getting the indices values out, so I tried this in my console:

```js
const arr = [1, 2]
const [x, y, ...{length}] = arr
console.log(x) // 1
console.log(y) // 2
console.log(length) // 0 | ??? isn't it should give me 2?
```

```js
// how about this...
const arr = [1, 2]
const {length} = arr
console.log(length) // 2 | ok well, it did work this way, but why not the destructuring assignment?
```

So, does anybody know why the `length` did not got assigned with value `2` in the first destructuring assignment? or did I found a bug in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What this does

```
[a, b, ...something] = someArray
```

is it takes the rest of the elements (index 2 and after) from `someArray` and puts them into a single variable as an array.

Doing

```
...{ pop, push }
```

takes two properties from that array: `Array.prototype.pop` and `Array.prototype.push`. But there aren't any more elements, because the original array had only 2 items, so doing

```
...{ length }
```

will give you 0.

If the original array *did* have more items, you'd see a length. For example:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const [x, y, ...{length}] = arr;

console.log(length);
```

The first two items are put into `x` and `y`. The last three items are taken as an array and then the `length` property is destructured from that array - so the length is 3.

Either add the number of destructured items previously to the length to get the *actual* length

```js
const arr = [1, 2]
const [x, y, ...{length}] = arr
const actualLength = length + 2; // because 2 items were destructured; x and y
console.log(x) // 1
console.log(y) // 2
console.log(actualLength);
```

Or use object destructuring syntax instead

```js
const arr = [1, 2]
const { 0: x, 1: y, length } = arr;
console.log(x) // 1
console.log(y) // 2
console.log(length);
```

Or, more understandable at a glance than either of the above - just do `const { length } = arr` on a separate line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was mislead by the `This allows you to simultaneously unpack the properties and indices of arrays.` thought I can also destructing the props of the whole Array object(of [1, 2])... therefore, I was expecting to see `2`. Now after understand how it really works, I can see that `const [...{length}] = arr`, will also gives me length = 2. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what happens when you only take one element off

```js
const arr = [1, 2]
const [x, ...{length}] = arr
console.log("x", x) // 1
console.log("length", length) // 1
```

Notice how the length is one, because you start with 2 elements, then get rid of 1, and `2 - 1` is 1.

Why does this happen? `...` means "rest", so it's the rest of the properties.

```js
const arr = [1, 2]
const [x, ...rest] = arr
console.log("x", x) // 1
console.log("rest", rest) // [2]
```

When you use `{` `}` you get a property off of the rest, so it's the same as saying

```js
const arr = [1, 2]
const [x, ...rest] = arr
console.log("x", x) // 1
const {length} = rest;
console.log("rest", rest) // [2]
console.log("length", length) // 1
```